How can I get private members of a mocked class?
Using the PrivateObject class I can access private members of a class.
But I cannot access private members if that class is mocked using Moq.
Example Code
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;
using Xunit;
using Assert = Xunit.Assert;

namespace MyNamespace;

public class Temp
{
    private int I { get; set; }

    public int PublicI
    {
        get => I;
        set => I = value;
    }

    public Temp(int i)
    {
        I = i;
    }
}

public class Testing
{
    [Fact]
    [Trait("Category", "Unit")]
    public void TestNormal()
    {
        var temp = new Temp(7);
        Assert.Equal(7, temp.PublicI);
        temp.PublicI = 8;
        Assert.Equal(8, temp.PublicI);

        var po = new PrivateObject(temp);
        var publicI = po.GetFieldOrProperty("PublicI");
        Assert.Equal(8, publicI);

        var privateI = po.GetFieldOrProperty("I", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        Assert.Equal(8, privateI);
    }

    [Fact]
    [Trait("Category", "Unit")]
    public void TestMocked()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<Temp>(7);
        Assert.Equal(7, mock.Object.PublicI);
        mock.Object.PublicI = 8;
        Assert.Equal(8, mock.Object.PublicI);

        var po = new PrivateObject(mock.Object);
        var publicI = po.GetFieldOrProperty("PublicI");
        Assert.Equal(8, publicI);

        // Following line throws System.MissingMethodException
        var privateI = po.GetFieldOrProperty("I", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        Assert.Equal(8, privateI);
    }
}

The line after the comment throws a MissingMethodException. Why doesn't it find my member?

What are you trying to test and why? That doesn't make sense to me.

Why would you try to test a mock object?

PrivateObject essentially works the same as using pure reflection. However I agree the above comments: why would you want that? Seems like you want to test your Sut and mock some parts of it. Anyway testing for private members is seldomly a good idea, and should only be done in between some refactoring or similar.

A Unittest should test a Unit and the surfaced behavior of that unit(the classes behavioral contract). What you test is a implementation detail so you are likely breaking test when changing code. That's the opposite of what you want at least in test driven development. Thats said we don't see the PrivateObject definition just the one for Temp. Maybe PrivateObject just don't have it?

@Ralf PrivateObject comes from Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting:.

Mock doesn't mock private members (it doesn't interfere into mocked class private affairs), e.g. having a guinea pig class
public class MyClass 
{
    public int MyMethod() => MyPrivateMethod() * 1000;

    private int MyPrivateMethod() => 123;   
}

And pure Reflection inspector
private static void PrivateMethods(object value) {
  var methodNames = value
      .GetType()
      .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
      .Select(item => item.Name);

  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, methodNames));
}

We can easily see the difference:
// Original class
PrivateMethods(new MyClass());

Console.WriteLine();

// Mocked class
Mock<MyClass> mock = new Mock<MyClass>();

PrivateMethods(mock.Object);

Output:
MyPrivateMethod
MemberwiseClone
Finalize

MemberwiseClone
Finalize

Note, that mock.Object is not MyClass:
// False
Console.WriteLine(mock.Object.GetType() == typeof(MyClass));
// Castle.Proxies.MyClassProxy
Console.WriteLine(mock.Object.GetType().FullName);

Finally, if you want method to be mocked, make anything but private (internal, protected, protected internal, private protected)
